# K8s Kf-serving: Using a different storage other than Google Cloud Storage

Tags: kubeflow

I'm following the tutorial from Kfserving documentation here:https://github.com/kubeflow/kfserving to Test KFServing Installation. However, in our corporate environment, we do not have the access to Google Cloud Storage which is defined in the following `.yaml` file. My question is -- do we have any alternatives to Google Cloud Storage such as uploading a local model artifact or using another corporate accessible storage?

```
apiVersion: "serving.kubeflow.org/v1alpha2"
kind: "InferenceService"
metadata:
  name: "sklearn-iris"
spec:
  default:
    predictor:
      sklearn:
        storageUri: "gs://kfserving-samples/models/sklearn/iris"
```

Comment: Yes it helps, thanks!

Comment: To add more, I found the information from this page that we can actually use different cloud storage :https://github.com/kubeflow/kfserving/blob/master/python/kfserving/README.md,